# How to Find the number of Clicks to Sharepoint Online site?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am currently working for a project and I have a requirement to find the number of click for the Sharepoint online Site and display that in the Power BI Report.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a reference to this article and you'll get what you want in the **OPTION 6: POWER BI OFFICE 365 ADOPTION PACK**: [6 ways to check SharePoint Usage reports](https://sharepointmaven.com/6-ways-check-sharepoint-usage-reports/).